# Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler directly setting the number of replicas

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to use the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler to scale my application. I already have a custom metric that specifies the desired number of pods.

`kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/mb/services/mb-metrics-exporter/channels`

This returns

```json
{
  "kind": "MetricValueList",
  "apiVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "describedObject": {
        "kind": "Service",
        "namespace": "mb-nascar",
        "name": "mb-nascar-metrics-exporter",
        "apiVersion": "/v1beta1"
      },
      "metricName": "channels",
      "timestamp": "2023-08-01T09:47:36Z",
      "value": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Where the channels value is the desired number of replicas.

I have created a HPA, however as expected when the channels value increases, the HPA continues to add pods to the maxReplicas value, as the channels metric never decreases.

I'm trying to set the number of replicas directly from the channels metric.

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: ingest-worker-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: StatefulSet
    name: ingest-worker
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 50
  metrics:
  - type: Object
    object:
      metric:
        name: channels
      describedObject:
        kind: Service
        apiVersion: v1
        name: mb-metrics-exporter
      target:
        type: Value 
        value: 1
```

I have reviewed the documentation and I cant find anything that looks like it will help.

Any help would be appreciated.